# Why is my SRAM so quickly filled? There are not more than 60 bytes

Tags: arduino-uno, sram

I have just gone through all my code. At max I use 60 bytes. I have done everything in order to minimize its usage - I even store booleans as bits, not bytes! What could be happening here?

The only thing that comes to my mind are extremely large arrays, like this:

```
const uint8_t SBoxes[8][4][16] PROGMEM;
```

However, these are stored in the program memory as you can see. How can I check they are really there and my memory usage? My code is too large to post it here.

EDIT:

IDE tells me (even though I believe it's very inaccurate):

> Sketch uses 7,898 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
>   Global variables use 1,023 bytes (49%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,025 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.

All my literal strings use F() and there are not many of them.

EDIT2:

[Code on pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/0ZduU2JJ) Just for a quick glance, it is really large.

EDIT3:

My `Serial` prints

```
ready
some numbers (that's ok I ask it to print out an array)
ENready
again numburs
Enready
...
```

I ask it to print `ready` at the very beginning of my program. I ask it to println `End of encr` near the end of my `setup` funciton, but as you see it never finishes the printing.

It always behaves like that when I run out of SRAM.

Comment: What does the IDE say how much space was used?

Comment: Please post the data declarations. Check that all literal strings use F().

Comment: I updated my question. Please, see the EDIT.

Comment: What does `avr-nm -Crtd --size-sort your_elf_file` tell you? Look at symbols of type `D`, `B` and `V`.

Comment: On what kind of file should I call it? All I have are .ino files. And it doesn't take my project file as an argument. It tells me it 'is not an ordinary file'.

Comment: Build the program with the “verbose compilation” option activated. You will see the IDE creates a file with a .elf extension in a temporary directory. That's the file you should give to avr-nm.

Comment: You are also using the LiquidCrystal library and `Serial` (which uses a 64 byte buffer). Removing all else, you end up with about 260 bytes already. Though, I have no idea where the other 750 bytes go to.

Comment: Oh I see, you have just taught me something new. [Here it is on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HexLXUwD)

Comment: About the `Serial` and LiquidCrystal: Yeah, I forgot about it. Thank you for pointing about, but I am afraid not even this solves the riddle.

Comment: If you want to learn a lot of details about the 1975 Data Encryption Standard (DES), implementing it from scratch will teach you a lot. However, if your goal is to actually encrypt something, perhaps it would be better to (a) use a more modern cipher such as Twofish or AES; or (b) use a pre-existing library; or both. See [Spaniakos](http://spaniakos.github.io/AES/), [AESLib](https://github.com/DavyLandman/AESLib), [AES-library](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=88890.0), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are asking yourself what is eating so much RAM, the first step
is to look at the symbol table in the ELF file. If you use a makefile, you
probably know where to find the ELF file. If you are using the Arduino
IDE, go to File / Preferences, check “Show verbose output during
compilation”, compile and look at the output: you will see the temporary
directory where the compiler puts your ELF file.

Now run the command `avr-nm -Crtd --size-sort your_elf_file` and look
for symbols of type 'D' (data), 'V' (vtable) and 'B' (BSS), in either
upper or lower case. On a Unix-style OS you would pipe through
`grep -i ' [dbv] '`. Running this on your program gives:

```
00000068 B tx_buffer
00000068 B rx_buffer
00000034 B Serial
00000021 B lcd
00000016 V vtable for HardwareSerial
00000008 V vtable for LiquidCrystal
00000004 B timer0_overflow_count
00000004 B timer0_millis
00000002 D __malloc_margin
00000002 D __malloc_heap_start
00000002 D __malloc_heap_end
00000002 B __flp
00000002 B __brkval
00000001 b timer0_fract
00000001 D encr
00000001 B debug
00000001 B EEPROM
```

Obviously, this cannot account for the 1,023 bytes of static RAM your
program is using. What this command misses is the literal arrays and
strings. These can be seen with the command
`avr-objdump -j .data -s your_elf_file`. The literal strings are quite
obvious in the output, the literal arrays less so. Running this on your
program gives a long listing starting with

```
Contents of section .data:
800100 00000005 2000010e 040d0102 0f0b0803  .... ...........
800110 0a060c05 09000700 0f07040e 020d010a  ................
```

Now, on the source code we see:

```cpp
const uint8_t SBoxes[8][4][16] PROGMEM = {
{{14,  4,  13,  1,   2, 15,  11,  8,   3, 10,   6, 12,   5,  9,   0,  7},
 { 0, 15,   7,  4,  14,  2,  13,  1,  10,  6,  12, 11,   9,  5,   3,  8},
 { 4,  1,  14,  8,  13,  6,   2, 11,  15, 12,   9,  7,   3, 10,   5,  0},
 {15, 12,   8,  2,   4,  9,   1,  7,   5, 11,   3, 14,  10,  0,   6, 13} },
 ...
```

If you translate this to hexadecimal, you get `0e 04 0d 01 02 0f...`,
which appears also by the end of the first line of previous listing. So
there is your culprit: all the big PROGMEM arrays. The compiler does not
honor the PROGMEM attribute on local variables.

My first thought was to make the arrays global, and this does solve the
problem. However, as pointed out by Mikael Patel in a comment, the
documentation on PROGMEM states that “variables must be either globally
defined, OR defined with the static keyword, in order to work with
PROGMEM.” Then, making the arrays `static const PROGMEM` is a cleaner
solution.

Comment: It can't. It doesn't make sense to.

Comment: I tested simply defining them as "static" where they stand and data size drops to 311 bytes.

Comment: I tried to take them out of the functions to make them global. To make sure the library works I called the input rigth above the arrays. As you can see the IDE says something different (Sketch uses 7,788 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 399 bytes (19%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,649 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.). But it is still out of SRAM - the program loops its Serial the same way as before.

Comment: There is actually a line in the Arduino PROGMEM documentation about this "Please note that variables must be either globally defined, OR defined with the static keyword, in order to work with PROGMEM." https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM

Comment: `But it is still out of SRAM - the program loops its Serial the same way as before.` - let's not jump to conclusions now. What do you mean "loops its Serial" exactly?

Comment: Is it printing `fff` a lot? Well, you told it to do that.

Comment: I use the Serial input for debugging. Once it starts printing gibberish or looping (that means it prints something and starts again from the beginning of the program) I know I have run out of SRAM. No, I mean in `Serial`, fff is for the lcdDisplay - it never comes to the command anyway, it starts looping before.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste into it what it is actually printing. We are now trying to guess what you are getting at.

Comment: I have just editted it to make it more clear, good idea.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on Edgar Bonet's answer and my comment under it, you cannot usefully put PROGMEM variables as local variables because local (non-static) variables have to be allocated on the stack.

```C++
void lookUpInSBox(size_t which, byte *address, byte* binaryOutcome, size_t addressFrom){

   ...

    const uint8_t SBoxes[8][4][16] PROGMEM = {

                             /*S1*/

   { {14,  4,  13,  1,   2, 15,  11,  8,   3, 10,   6, 12,   5,  9,   0,  7},
     { 0, 15,   7,  4,  14,  2,  13,  1,  10,  6,  12, 11,   9,  5,   3,  8},
     { 4,  1,  14,  8,  13,  6,   2, 11,  15, 12,   9,  7,   3, 10,   5,  0},
     {15, 12,   8,  2,   4,  9,   1,  7,   5, 11,   3, 14,  10,  0,   6, 13}    },
```

You could make them global. But if you prefer  not to do that, put `static` in front of them. Doing that on your code reduced it to 247 bytes.

```
Global variables use 247 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,801 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
```

---

You expect a bit more than the 60 you counted. The serial buffers take a bit (128 bytes).

See [Putting constant data into program memory (PROGMEM)](http://www.gammon.com.au/progmem) for more information. On a tiny sketch I found the following 346 bytes already in use:

- 34 bytes for the HardwareSerial instance (Serial)
- 64 bytes for the Serial transmit buffer
- 64 bytes for the Serial receive buffer
- 4 bytes for the Serial transmit buffer head and tail pointers
- 4 bytes for the Serial receive buffer head and tail pointers
- 9 bytes for keeping track of millis / micros
- 4 bytes for memory allocation (__malloc_heap_start, __malloc_margin)
- 128 bytes for the heap safety margin
- 6 bytes for a few nested function calls (main -> setup -> getFreeMemory)
- 16 bytes for the compiler vtable for HardwareSerial
- 4 bytes for variables __brkval and __flp (used in memdebug)
- 2 bytes pushed onto the stack in main (to save registers)
- 2 bytes pushed onto the stack in setup (to save registers)
- 4 bytes pushed onto the stack in getFreeMemory (to save registers)
- 1 byte because the stack pointer starts at 0x8FF rather than 0x900

The sketch on my page used dynamic memory allocation so it used a bit more than yours does (for keeping track of it).

---

> Once it starts printing gibberish or looping (that means it prints something and starts again from the beginning of the program) I know I have run out of SRAM

I'm a bit puzzled by all the `new`/`delete` you are doing. Why do that? For example:

```C++
byte *E;
E = new byte[48/8];  
for(size_t i = 0; i < 48; i++){
    insertBit( E, i, bitValue( R, E_BIT[i]-1 ) );
}

// XOR Kn and  E(Rn-1)
byte KxorE[48/8]; 
for (size_t i = 0; i < 48; i++){
    insertBit( KxorE, i, bitValue( K, i ) ^ bitValue( E, i ) );
}
delete[] E;
```

Massive amounts of dynamic memory allocation may fragment memory. Can't you rewrite to not do that? You can pass arrays by reference, it just seems weird (and slow) to do all that allocation.

Comment: You mean like `const uint8_t SBoxes[8][4][16] PROGMEM`? I have tried it and although the IDE lowered the numbers of memory usage, the program still loops its `Serial` input - it is still out of SRAM :( Even if I add your additional bytes to my numbers we get nowhere near 2000.

Comment: I don't understand that. Therefore it is not out of SRAM, unless you dynamically allocate memory a lot. See my comment under Edgar Bonet's answer.

Comment: See my amended answer about dynamic allocation.

Comment: I need both of the `E` and `KxorE` arrays. What I can do is not to delete them, but not much more. Originally I was worried about the SRAM so I deleted everything I could. Of course I am going to optimalize its speed, but only when it runs. But thank you for that tip, I didn't know memory allocation would be that slow.

Comment: It's not *that* slow but it is slower than not doing it. If you use local variables rather than dynamic ones, then you save the allocation / deallocation. You would need to modify the functions to take an argument by reference, or pass a pointer (depending on whether or not the function modifies the argument).

Comment: If you redesign to not use dynamic memory, at least you know that once you have enough memory at the start, you won't use any more of it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Maybe you have noticed that in order to save even more bytes I use the EEPROM. Well, I can't save more space. That means that even reprogramming it would be useless.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't save more space"? If you switch from dynamic allocation to using static arrays, it should work. You have heaps of RAM free (only using 12% at present).

Comment: Ok, I guess I don't understand the heap anymore. I thought that pretty much the stack and the heap both occupy the same space - one on each end and the program collides once they have no more space between them. But basically it doesn't matter if I have int[5] or new int[5]. I am going to rewrite it to static arrays.

Comment: I've been just told that if I save the arrays in PROGMEM I need to use pgm_read_byte / pgm_read_word to read them. Might this solve the problem?

Comment: @SlowerPhoton: “_it doesn't matter if I have int[5] or new int[5]._”. With the former, there is no risk of memory fragmentation, and there is no risk of you forgetting to delete the array. And to answer your last comment, not using the pgm\_read\_\*() functions is clearly a bug. Whether it's the _only_ bug in your program, I cannot say.

Comment: `I've been just told that if I save the arrays in PROGMEM I need to use pgm_read_byte / pgm_read_word to read them.` - absolutely. They are different address spaces. I didn't look at your code in that level of detail to notice that you weren't.